# How to make partially visible adjacent elements of the carousel

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, onsen-ui

I have a merry-go-round, it works but as I understand it, she scrolls through the screenshots and so I can not positiozionirovat elements as in the design!

there is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hplgs.png)
should be so
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSTG5.png)

```
<v-ons-carousel fullscreen
                        swipeable
                        auto-scroll
                        overscrollable
                        :index.sync="carouselIndex"
                        class="carousel_main"
        >
            <v-ons-carousel-item class="carousel_item" v-for="(item, key) in items"
                                 :key="key">
                <v-ons-row vertical-align="center"
                           style="text-align: center;"
                           class="carousel_row">
                    <v-ons-col style="align-self: flex-end;" width="50%">
                        <img :src="item.img" alt="">
                    </v-ons-col>
                    <v-ons-col width="100%">
                        {{ item.title }}
                        <br>
                        <span">
                          {{ item.text }}
                        </span>
                    </v-ons-col>
                </v-ons-row>
            </v-ons-carousel-item>
        </v-ons-carousel>



data() {
            return {
                carouselIndex: 0,
                imgPhone,
                imgHome,
                imgPayList,
                items: [
                    {
                        img: imgPhone,
                        title: 'Пополняйте счет на мобильном телефоне',
                        text: 'Пополняйте мобильный с минимальной комиссией',
                    },
                    {
                        img: imgHome,
                        title: 'Оплачивайте более 1000 услуг прямо с телефона',
                        text: 'Коммунальные платежи, интернет и ТВ, онлайн игры и многое другое',
                    },
                    {
                        img: imgPayList,
                        title: 'Создавайте шаблоны платежей',
                        text: 'Приложение автоматически будет оплачивать ваши услуги',
                    },
                ],

            };
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The carousel does not provide a way to show neighbors, so you have to do it yourself. Where you have:

```
<v-ons-col style="align-self: flex-end;" width="50%">
   <img :src="item.img" alt="">
</v-ons-col>
```

you will need to have something like

```
<v-ons-col style="align-self: flex-end;" width="50%">
    <img v-if="key > 0" class="neighbor" :src="items[key-1].img">
    <img :src="item.img" alt="">
    <img v-if="key < items.length - 1" class="neighbor" :src="items[key + 1].img">
</v-ons-col>
```

You will probably need to wrap the three images in a div to make a row of them, and style `.neighbor` with a reduced opacity and scale.